# SQL: how to group by next/following record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table that looks like this

```
date | type | group
jan1 | a | 1
jan2 | a | 1
jan3 | b | 2
jan4 | c | 3
jan5 | a | 4
jan6 | b | 5
jan7 | b | 5
```

How would I write a SQL script that would count the following/next 'type' value and assign it to the same group?

Tried using aggregate functions rank/sum/count to no avail.

Comment: Please include the expected result.

Comment: Just an aside, you should really avoid reserved words like Date, Type and Group.   Batting 1,000 here  :)    Take a peek at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "Date" column is an actual date.  You can use the window function
`lag() over ()` and `sum() over ()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([date] date,[type] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('01/01/2023','a')
,('01/02/2023','a')
,('01/03/2023','b')
,('01/04/2023','c')
,('01/05/2023','a')
,('01/06/2023','b')
,('01/07/2023','b')



;with cte as (
Select *
      ,flag=case when lag([type],1) over (order by [date]) <> [type] then 1 else 0 end
 From @YourTable
)
Select date
      ,type
      ,grp = sum(flag) over (order by date) + 1
 From  cte
 Order by Date
```

**Results**

```
date        type    grp
2023-01-01  a       1
2023-01-02  a       1
2023-01-03  b       2
2023-01-04  c       3
2023-01-05  a       4
2023-01-06  b       5
2023-01-07  b       5
```